# Unable to fetch value from ansible_devices variable if special character in key

Tags: json, ansible

I am using gather fact variable to get size from [ansible_devices variable](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts). for some host I am getting variable `"ansible_devices": { "sda"` and for few server getting `"ansible_devices": { "cciss!c0d0"`.

**Problem:-** When I am using `ansible` variable `{{ ansible_devices.sda.size }}` its working perfectly. But when I am trying to access value from `{{ ansible_devices.cciss!c0d0.size }}` in my playbook then it is not returning any value whereas in json `ansible_devices` variable there is value exist for  `{{ ansible_devices.cciss!c0d0.size }}`.

```
     {
        "ansible_devices": {
            "cciss!c0d0": {
                "holders": [],
                "host": "RAID bus controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array Controller (rev 03)",
                "model": "LOGICAL VOLUME",
                "partitions": {},
                "removable": "0",
                "rotational": "1",
                "scheduler_mode": "cfq",
                "sectors": "143299800",
                "sectorsize": "512",
                "size": "68.33 GB",
                "support_discard": "0",
                "vendor": "HP"
            }
        },
        "item": ""
    }
```

It might be the case special character in a `ansible` variable json key that's why I am unable to fetch its value.
Can anyone suggest me how can I access `{{ ansible_devices.cciss!c0d0.size }}` value here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ansible_devices` ansible variable from its edge `hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_devices"]` then it will give me correct value. I don't know what is the exact reason behind this but this is trick for this problem.

```
{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_devices"]["cciss!c0d0"]["size"] }}
```

I getting this solution in [Ansible Project Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ansible-project/TsBx_B7JYxU/discussion)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in javascript , you can also fetch the JSON data as :

```
ansible_devices["cciss!c0d0"]
```

It will display the whole object under **cciss!c0d0** key and then you can use the inbuild function like size , normally.

So try to use :

```
ansible_devices["cciss!c0d0"].size
```

Comment: This question doesn't related to JavaScript.

Comment: have you tried the solution though , also you never mentioned any language in which you have to parse the data. please edit your question before down-voting other answers.

Comment: I have not downvoted sumit. As I have added `ansible` tag in this so its obvious question related to `ansible`. and also I have mentioned I facing this problem in ansible playbook.